# MYSQL - get the rows where one column A is less than column B

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table (showing only relevant columns)

```
ID | product_name | stock | stock_level
6  | test name    | 5     | 4
 7 | test name 2  | 3     | 9
```

I have a lot more rows in my database.

In MYSQL, how can I get every row where the stock value is less than the stock_level value?

Comment: So you are working with a relational database and haven't learned there is a WHERE clause, yet? I suggest you learn at least the database basics before coming here.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE stock < stock_level
```

That would return row2 (stock = 3, stock_level= 9) but not row1 (stock = 5, stock_level= 4).

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($myslqi, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE stock < stock_level")) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: See table definition: stock_level, not stock_value. And maybe add the semicolon at the end...

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the field name. I've left the semi-colon out as this has no effect in this example (and bad habits are hard to break!).